# TomSwift / TSAlertView ios 5 ARC version

Tags: ios5

1. Will the apple allow us to use our own customized alertView ?
2. I find this TSAlertView is not compatible with ios 5(ARC) . I just remove all the 'auto release ' 'retain' from the .m file. now it does't work. when show it. it always print 'TSAlertViewController dealloc' . Do you know why ?
3. I just want a Alert View that I can change the background image , button image or someting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert TSAlertView to use it in ARC-enabled project. You can disable ARC only for TSAlertView. There is the instruction: [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

I've just successfully used TSAlertView in my ARC-enabled project.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use your own custom view instead of an alert view, yes.
2. ARC is about more than just removing retains and release. But, there is a convertor to help you and it is available in Xcode's Refector Menu.
3. See the answer to 1.

Comment: Thanks.I use XCode's Refactor to covert TSAlertView successfully . but it doesn't work . prompt the same error as my 2nd point...

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking.

Comment: sorry. Could you help me convert this project to iOS5,6 ARC version? https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView

Comment: Sorry - no. If I work on Open Source projects it's because I choose to, not to answer an Stack Overflow question.